# tkinter GUI app with camera on closed camera is still running

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

In tkinter window I have camera from OpenCV

```
cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

When I click on Button [X] in the corner app is closed but camera is still runing.
Now I have 2 case

-1. case if I put only quit() window is [Not Responding] and OS kill window. When I try next time run application camera is working normally.

```
self.root = tk.Tk()

self.root.quit()
```

-2. case if I put quit() and destroy() window is closed perfect. 
When I try next time run application camera is black because camera is still running.

```
self.root = tk.Tk()

self.root.quit()
self.root.destroy()
```

And My final question is I want 1. case but I want window close normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should release the capture stream at the end :

```
self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
self.root = tk.Tk()

# [...]

self.stream.release()
self.root.quit()
```

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) you can grab some doc about openCV.